# Using the .Find Function VBA - not returning the first value

Tags: vba, excel

I have written a code excerpt for a larger program to test proof of concept. (Hence the small amount of code.) The idea behind the main code is for the user to generate an array using a Custom UserForm with check-boxes, then search the array for all mentions of "1" i.e. when the check-boxes have been selected. Then use the row number of the array to load a series of extra UserForms based on which check-boxes were selected. I imagine there are easier ways to do this, but this is the method that I have chosen, my coding experience with VBA is fairly limited!

I've attached an example of the array that is generated.

[image: An test example of arrey generated by the main code]

When I run the code, it works as inteneded except for the case when
Cells (1,2) = 1

Can anyone spot why this is, I've been struggaling over this for some time right now.

```
Sub Array_Finder()

    Dim StartFinder As String
    Dim StartFinderZero As String
    Dim StartFinderCheck As String

    i = 4 : j = 1
    StartFinderZero = 0 : StartFinderCheck = i + 2
    For StartFinderTest = 1 To i + 1
        StartFinder = StartFinderZero + 1
        If StartFinderCheck > StartFinder Then
            StartFinderZero = Range(Cells(StartFinder, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2)).Find _
                (What:="1", after:=Cells(StartFinder, 2), searchdirection:=xlNext).Row
            Cells(StartFinderTest, 3) = StartFinderZero
        Else
            MsgBox ("here")
            Exit For
        End If
    Next StartFinderTest
End Sub
```

Comment: @Tomm I don't usualy comment on other people editing, but in what bizarre world *genorate* and *arrey* are correct?

Comment: @AntiDrondert I find it interesting why I have edited it like that.

Comment: What is the expected output? Also, all your variables should be `Dim`med as `Long` not `String` Are you expecting to see the row in column `C` of where the value has been found?

Comment: @Tom Yes that is correct, for the example image posted, id would expeted Column C to go 1,2,4,5 rather than 2,4,5.

Comment: To be honest I'm a bit confused at your approach. You're returning the row number when the value in column 2 is `1` and are wanting it to return that row? But, yet you are searching from that row down to the end of the range. You could solve this simply with `=IF(B1=1, ROW(),"")` in `C1`

Comment: @Tom, i'll try and explain it more clearly for you. Colum A is just 1,2,3 etc (this number is used a referance and is probally redundent) Column B is either 1 or 0 depending on what CheckBoxs are selected on a previous UserForm. Then the idea behind this is that a need to find a way to run a squence of userforms so checkbox1 if ticked will open UserForm1, CheckBox2 will open UserForm2 etc. And for this Column C has a list of all number that represent which UserForms need to be open. Does that help?

Comment: @Tom I'm not really sure what the `=IF(B1 = 1, Row(),"")` is producing? . Does it basically search Cell B1 for 1??

Comment: It tests if Cell `B1` is 1 (as your code does) and returns the row number if it is (as your code does)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

With the usage of your code:

```
Sub ArrayFinder()

    Dim StartFinder As Long
    Dim StartFinderZero As String
    Dim StartFinderCheck As String
    i = 4: j = 1
    StartFinderZero = 0: StartFinderCheck = i + 2

    For StartFinderTest = 1 To i + 1
        StartFinder = StartFinderZero + 1
        If StartFinderCheck > StartFinder Then    
            With Range(Cells(StartFinder, 2), Cells(i + 1, 2))
                Debug.Print "row" & vbTab & .Cells(.Cells.Count).Row
                Debug.Print "address" & vbTab & .Address
                Debug.Print "after"; vbTab & .Cells(.Cells.Count).Address
                StartFinderZero = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count)).Row
            End With    
            Cells(StartFinderTest, 3) = StartFinderZero
        Else
            Debug.Print "here"
            Exit For
        End If
    Next StartFinderTest

End Sub
```

This is what you get at the immediate window:

```
row 5
address $B$1:$B$5
after    $B$5
row 5
address $B$2:$B$5
after    $B$5
```

The trick is the following (the After parameter from [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/range-find-method-excel)):

*The cell after which you want the search to begin. This corresponds to the position of the active cell when a search is done from the user interface. Notice that After must be a single cell in the range. Remember that the search begins after this cell; **the specified cell isn't searched until the method wraps back around to this cell**. If you do no specify this argument, the search starts after the cell in the upper-left corner of the range.*

Thus you give the last cell possible as a start. It knows that it should start **After** it. So, it theoretically has nothing better to do and simply starts from the beginning of the range. The idea of the `After` parameter is to set the last value that would be checked. ***Thus, if we have only one value it is always returned correctly***, no matter of the `After` parameter. With more than one value, it returns the first value it finds.

Thus, in the code above, because of the usage of **After** the `.Find()` searches the cells in the following sequence:

B1>B2>B3>B4>B5

Without the **After** the sequence is the following:

B2>B3>B4>B5>B1

---

To illustrate it better, imagine that you have two different Ranges like this:

[image]

With the left one, if you search the row of `1` you will always be ok, even without selecting the after parameter, using this code:

```
Sub TestMe()
    Dim myR     As Range
    Dim myS     As Range
    Set myS = Range("B1:B5") 'change the range
    With myS
        Set myR = .Find(1)
        Debug.Print myR.Row
        Set myR = .Find(1, after:=.Cells(.Cells.Count))
        Debug.Print myR.Row
    End With
End Sub
```

The range on the right is the tricky one, because it also has `1` twice. Thus the `after` is a must there, in order to get the value from the first cell.If you try it you would get `2` and `1` displayed on the immediate window.

*And pretty much this is why at some point I have decided to use a slow method which simply loops in the range and checks for the values, instead of the built-in `.Find()`* [GitHub link to LastThings](https://github.com/Vitosh/VBA_personal/blob/master/Boilerplate/LastThings.vb).

Comment: Thank you ever so much, if you dont mind can you please explain the `.Cells.Count` part. From what i understand it search a that cell bu ti dont understand how it defines which cell is being used

Answer (score 1):

I assume everything happens on a sheet. It works for data you provided.

```
Sub MyAnswer()
    Dim lRow As Long ' Number of rows (or last row)
    Dim rngCheckBoxes As Range ' Range of values
    Dim vArr()
    ' Calculate last row
    lRow = ActiveSheet.Range("A" & ActiveSheet.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    ' Define range of checkboxes' numbers
    Set rngCheckBoxes = ActiveSheet.Range("A1","A" & lRow)
    ' Replace all zeroes with empty string
    rngCheckBoxes.Offset(0,1).Replace "0", "", xlWhole
    ' Put all values from defined range into array
    ' where according values from column next to it aren't blank
    vArr = rngCheckBoxes.Offset(0,1).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).Offset(0,-1).Value
    ' Insert array values into column "C"
    ActiveSheet.Range("C1").Resize(Ubound(vArr),1).Value = vArr
End Sub
```

Comment: thank you for the answer, it was very kind of you. Your answer works well, but I'll go with Vityata's one as the code is slightly eaiser to understand for me. Thank you for the help though :)

Comment: @CptGoodar No problem :)