# Excel VBA code for finding corresponding pairs of data in two columns

Tags: excel, vba

I have a problem with the following code. I have data in columns A and C and want to find matching pairs that are identical in these two columns (column A and C). The pairs should receive an unique identifier in column B and D. This way I can filter out corresponding pairs from column A and C and have two remaining columns that cannot be matched. However, my code keeps looping trough the data when there are duplicates within a column and keeps assigning higher reference numbers.

```
Sub match()
    Dim c As Range, fn As Range, ref As Long
    ref = 1
        For Each c In Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
            If c <> "" And c <> 0 Then
                Set fn = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).Find(c.Value, , xlValues, xlWhole)
                    If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                        adr = fn.Address
                        Do
                            If fn.Offset(, 1) = "" Then
                                c.Offset(, 1) = ref
                                fn.Offset(, 1) = ref
                                ref = ref + 1
                            Else
                                Set fn = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp)).FindNext(fn)
                            End If
                        Loop While fn.Address <> adr
                    End If
            End If
        Next
        On Error Resume Next
        Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "Not found"
        Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "Not Found"
        On Error GoTo 0
        Err.Clear
    End Sub
```

[image]

Does anyone know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

You may benefit from MATCH in array form with `Evaluate` to fill the column D. The column B is the easy part, just MAX+1

```
Sub TEST()
Dim i As Long, j As Long
Dim rng_c As Range
Dim rng_b As Range
Dim LR As Long
Dim SR As Long
Dim Myf As WorksheetFunction
Set Myf = Application.WorksheetFunction 'to save some time typing

SR = 1 'starting row of data
LR = Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row 'last row of data in column A

Set rng_b = Range("B" & SR & ":B" & LR) ' for column B
Set rng_c = Range("C" & SR & ":C" & LR) ' for column C

rng_b.Clear 'must be empty
Range("D" & SR & ":d" & LR).Clear 'must be empty

For i = SR To LR Step 1
    If Myf.CountIf(rng_c, Range("A" & i).Value) = 0 Then
        Range("B" & i).Value = "Not found"
    Else
        Range("B" & i).Value = Myf.Max(rng_b) + 1
    End If
Next i

j = SR

For i = SR To LR Step 1
    If Range("B" & i).Value <> "Not found" Then
        j = Evaluate("MATCH(A" & i & ",C" & SR & ":C" & LR & "&D" & SR & ":D" & LR & ",0)")
        Range("D" & j).Value = Range("B" & i).Value
    End If
Next i

Set rng_b = Nothing
Set rng_c = Nothing
Set Myf = Nothing


End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: Column B gets filled with numbers and 'not found;, column D only gets numbers an not a 'not found'. After this I get a Run-time error '13' Type Mismatch in this part:

 j = Evaluate("MATCH(A" & i & ",C" & SR & ":C" & LR & "&D" & SR & ":D" & LR & ",0)")

Comment: @Vlietstar What are the values of SR and LR when you get the error? Where is located your data? Did  you debug it to see the exact moment where it fails? did you make sure everything is properly referenced addressing rangeS?

Answer (score 0):

You could do this without VBA at all, actually.
In D2, write this Formula:

```
=IF(COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $C:$C, $C2)>1, IF(COUNTIFS($A$1:$A2, $A2, $C$1:$C2, $C2)=1, MAX($D$1:$D1)+1, XLOOKUP($A2 & $C2, $A$1:$A1 & $C$1:$C1, $D$1:$D1)), "Not Found")
```

Then copy that down column D, and make column B equal to column D

Comment: Because this uses `XLOOKUP` function, it will only work on Excel for office 365. If you aren't in office 365 you'd need to add another helper column to get the formula to work, see [Vlookup with multiple criteria](https://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/2440-excel-vlookup-multiple-criteria.html)

Answer (score 0):

There are several ways of doing this, but you were nearly there!
Here are some slight adjustments:

```
Sub match()

'''screenupdating false, calc to manual to speed up code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim c As Range, fn As Range, ref As Long
    
    'setting your ranges for clarity
    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    
    Set rng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    
    '''necessary for rerunning
    rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    rng2.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    
    ref = 1
    For Each c In rng
        If c <> "" And c <> 0 Then
        
            'adding After:=rng2.Cells.Count
            Set fn = rng2.Find(c.Value, rng2.Cells(rng2.Cells.Count), xlValues, xlWhole)
                If Not fn Is Nothing Then
                    
                    ''' placed this back here
                    adr = fn.Address
                    Do
                    
                    '''
                    'place inside Do ... Loop While
                    '''adr = fn.Address
                    '''
                        
                        If fn.Offset(, 1) = "" Then
                            c.Offset(, 1) = ref
                            fn.Offset(, 1) = ref
                            ref = ref + 1
                            
                            ''' but we do need it here to get out of infinite loop
                            ''' in case
                            adr = fn.Address
                            
                        Else
                            Set fn = rng2.FindNext(fn)
                        End If
                    Loop While fn.Address <> adr
                End If
        End If
    Next
    
    On Error Resume Next
    Range("B2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "Not found"
    Range("D2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp).Offset(, 1)).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeBlanks) = "Not found" '''minor correction: "Not found" (F -> f)
    On Error GoTo 0
    Err.Clear

'''screenupdating true again, calc to auto
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Problem 1: you forget to add the `After` parameter in `.Find(...)`. See [Using the .Find Function VBA - not returning the first value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47938876/using-the-find-function-vba-not-returning-the-first-value) on why you need it.

<s>Problem 2: the statement `adr = fn.Address` should be inside the `Do ... Loop While`, else you won't step out of the loop until after the last match; as a result you just kept overwriting the value in c.Offset(, 1) for `A8` (leading to `6`) and adding values for all its matches in column C (which explains values `4, 5, 6`).</s>

---

**Edit**: Problem 2 in the strikethrough text above was real, my suggestion on how to fix it quite ignorant. It will cause an infinite loop for a duplicate in `rng` that does have one or more matches in `rng2`, but *less* matches than its own count in `rng`. E.g. if `rng` has `x` 3 times, and `rng2` has `x` twice, the code will loop forever when it gets to the 3rd `x` and crash Excel. So sorry. Pure luck that the dummy data didn't contain such an example.

Correct solution: keep `adr = fn.Address` were it was, but add the same statement inside the `If fn.Offset(, 1) = "" Then` statement. Now, it should work. Code above updated. Triple apostrophes in the code indicate corrections. Added some minor syntax for better performance.

However, as I was testing on a much larger set, I noticed this code was slow. I've found a rather different solution with much better performance, which I will post as a different answer in a sec (in accordance with [SO etiquette](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25209/what-is-the-official-etiquette-on-answering-a-question-twice).

Comment: Thanks this one is working! However when I use it on a bigger dataset with around 400 values per column Excel crashes... Do  you know why?

Comment: It keeps looping on a value in Column A when that value is repeated on the next row. For example if the value "xxx" is in row 15 and "xxx" is also in row 16 of column A the VBA keeps looping.

Comment: Right. I’ll have a look a bit later today. Should be fixable

Comment: thank you it now works with larger data sets!

Answer (score 0):

In my other answer I focused on improving your initial code, since you almost got there yourself, and I think one should encourage people's efforts. However, on a larger set, performance wasn't great, so I had a look to see if we could find improvement with a different method. The answer, I think, is "yes". The following solution stores the values from `rng2` in an array and on every match alters that match within the array (by adding `Chr(1) & ref` to the init value). At the end we use another loop to populate `rng2.Offset(,1)` with the `refs` through `Split()(1)` . This way, each new match will simply be the correct match for the new pair, thus avoiding many unnecessary `.find` commands. Below comparison of 2 tests.

In this snippet "Find_method" refers to code in other answer, "Array_method" refers to answer below.

[image]

I'd say, we have ourselves a clear winner. Suggestions for further improvement are of course welcome! Code as follows, with added comments to explain what it does:

```
Sub matchPairs()

'screenupdating false, calc to manual to speed up code
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim c As Range, fn As Range
    Dim ref As Long, c_match As Long, i As Long

    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    
    'set ranges
    Set rng = Range("A2", Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = Range("C2", Cells(Rows.Count, 3).End(xlUp))
    
    'clear offsets (not strictly necessary for rerun)
    rng.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    rng2.Offset(0, 1).ClearContents
    
    'drop rng2 inside array
    Dim DirArray() As Variant
    DirArray = Application.Transpose(rng2.Value)
    
    ref = 1 'counter
    
    'looping through init rng
    For Each c In rng
    
        'get position match c.Value in DirArray; will throw error if no match
        On Error Resume Next
        c_match = Application.match(c.Value, DirArray, 0)
        
        'handle error
        If Err.Number <> 0 Then
            c_match = 0
            
            'reset error handling
            Err.Clear
            On Error GoTo 0
        End If
        
        If c_match = 0 Then
            
            'no match
            c.Offset(, 1) = "Not found"
        
        Else
        
            'assign counter
            c.Offset(, 1) = ref
            
            'alter match in array, so it won't show up as a match again
                'Chr(1) (Start of Header, non-printable ASCII char) won't occur in your data
                'we can use it as the delimiter for Split below
            DirArray(c_match) = DirArray(c_match) & Chr(1) & ref
            
            'increment counter
            ref = ref + 1
        
        End If
        
    Next
    
    'loop over array, and check for presence Chr(1) in each value
    For i = LBound(DirArray) To UBound(DirArray)
    
        If InStr(DirArray(i), Chr(1)) = 0 Then
    
            'we didn't alter this entry: it was never found
            rng2.Cells(i).Offset(, 1) = "Not found"
            
        Else
    
            'Chr(1) present, get second value from Split array, and put in the offset
            rng2.Cells(i).Offset(, 1) = Split(DirArray(i), Chr(1))(1)
        
        End If
    
    Next i

'screenupdating true again, calc to auto
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```